# Create Spreadsheet from Multiple Queries

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet

In try to create a spreadsheet that is generated from multiple queries, the following code only generates one row of data and not the entire spreadsheet:

```
<cfset filenametouse = 'Usage_Report' />
<cfset theDir = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) /> 
<cfset theFile = theDir & filenametouse & ".xls" /> 

<cflock name="fileActionSentItems" type="exclusive" timeout="30" throwontimeout="true">
     <cfset SpreadsheetObj = spreadsheetNew()>
     <cfset fcol = {}>
     <cfset fcol.dataformat = "@">

     <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(SpreadsheetObj, "Part Number, Description, Allocated, On Hand, Pending Receipt, Job Count, Qty Needed, Qty Issued, Order Count, Qty Ordered, Qty Shipped")>

     <cfoutput>
          <cfset SpreadsheetAddRows(SpreadsheetObj,"#getParts.partnum#, #getParts.partdescription#, #getParts.allocated#, #getParts.onhand#, #receiptdata.recqty#, #jobdata.JobCount#, #jobdata.QtyNeeded#, #jobdata.qtySent#, #orderdata.ordercount#, #orderdata.ordered#, #orderdata.shipqty#")>
     </cfoutput>

     <cfset SpreadsheetFormatColumn(SpreadsheetObj,fcol,11)>
     <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="SpreadsheetObj" sheetname="Sheet1" overwrite="true" />
</cflock>
```

The spreadsheetAddRows isn't creating the data to populate the rows.  What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the query object instead of a single row of data.

```
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRows(SpreadsheetObj, getParts) >
```

As an aside, you probably do not need to lock that whole section. If the lock is intended to prevent concurrent file access, you only need to lock the code writing the sheet to disk. (Depending on your needs, you might also use a more granular name. But that is just a guess.)

Comment: This does help, but the last 7 columns get data from queries other than get parts.  How do I incorporate them?

Comment: Why not just do a JOIN and pull all the values needed in one query? You could output them separately by calling `SpreadsheetAddRows` twice, once with each query -OR- stitch the two queries together but only if the two queries have the same number of records - in the exact same order. Otherwise, the results may be misaligned.

Comment: ...or do a query-of-queries to get all of the data into a single query object.

Comment: Yeah, if you really cannot use a JOIN a QoQ on a key column would be better as it assures the right results are matched up.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looping through the query to assign more than one row. Because you don't specify what position the values should come from, they're being assigned from the first record in each query.

Create another query containing everything you want in the spreadsheet with queryNew()

```
<cfset newQuery = queryNew("partNo,desc,allocated,onHand,rendingReceipt,jobCount,qtyNeeded,qtyIssued,orderCount,qtyOrdered,qtyShipped","varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar,integer,integer,integer,integer,integer,integer,integer,integer") />
```

... etc, assigning cells as you go. When you have a complete query object, then you can add that to spreadsheetAddRows(spreadsheetObj,newQuery) />

If you find the spreadsheet creation to be too slow, you may want to check out POI Utility at http://www.bennadel.com/projects/poi-utility.htm Not as configurable as the spreadsheet options, but faster for some work loads.